# spring framework build error

Tags: spring

I am trying to build spring framework (both trunk and 3.0.5 Release). The build fails with the error was shown below. Steps taken.

1. svn co https://src.springsource.org/svn/spring-framework/trunk spring-framework
   or svn co https://src.springsource.org/svn/spring-framework/tags/spring-framework-3.0.5.RELEASE spring-framework-3.0.5.RELEASE
2. cd build-spring-framework
3. ant

Unfortunately, I am building on windows machine. Java version shows
java version "1.6.0_16"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_16-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.2-b01, mixed mode)

thanks.

```
[s:javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
  [s:javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:62)
  [s:javac]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
  [s:javac]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor151.invoke(Unknown Source)
  [s:javac]
  [s:javac] ----------
   [subant] Leaving directory: C:\Work\SpringFramework\spring-framework-3.0.5.RELEASE\org.springframework.web

BUILD FAILED
C:\Work\SpringFramework\spring-framework-3.0.5.RELEASE\spring-build\multi-bundle\artifact.xml:60: The following error oc
curred while executing this line:
C:\Work\SpringFramework\spring-framework-3.0.5.RELEASE\spring-build\multi-bundle\common.xml:86: The following error occu
rred while executing this line:
C:\Work\SpringFramework\spring-framework-3.0.5.RELEASE\spring-build\common\artifact.xml:43: The following error occurred
 while executing this line:
C:\Work\SpringFramework\spring-framework-3.0.5.RELEASE\spring-build\common\common.xml:161: The following error occurred
while executing this line:
C:\Work\SpringFramework\spring-framework-3.0.5.RELEASE\spring-build\standard\common.xml:29: java.lang.reflect.Invocation
TargetException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I am still to correct it.. but the actual cause was

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

I remember I have to increase the XX:MaxPermSize VM argument, and going through the option. Sorry for the trouble.

Edit:
adding a system variable ANT_OPTS with value -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Xmx256m did the trick.

Comment: trying with set ANT_OPTS=”-Xms512m -Xmx512m”

Answer (score 1):

Even using ANT_OPTS="-Xms768m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m" the build is failling. There is no PermGen error anymore but the unit tests are failling.
Whereas I'm just trying to use build/IVY to get all dependencies becouse I just need to debug spring code to learn things that are not in the docs, and considering that Spring code is ok, I'm disabling all the tests that are failling but I think that shouldn't exists such errors.
I will try to make a ant clean, to erase the IVY repository chache and start all again.
Actually I just want to learn what configurations I must to change to build my own HttpMessageConverter to use with @ResponseBody to do Json things with Gson and not with Jackson.

Comment: yes. the unit tests fail. i noticed that the tests that are failing have the @Ignore annotation on them, but despite that, those tests run... I wonder why...