# (Spring + JSP + jQuery-AJAX + JSON ) setting environment for UTF-8 issue?

Tags: java, jquery, spring, utf-8

I am doing a `chat project` in `java` with `Spring 3.x` which needs `Multi-language support`.

Here is what I have done.

My JSP has:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

My `web.xml` has:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

In my `Tomcat server.xml` has:

```
  <Connector (...) URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

My my `Java environment` has:

```
  JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS     -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

In my `Spring-controller` has:

```
@RequestMapping(value="sendMessage.html",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public  @ResponseBody String sendMessage(HttpSession session,@RequestParam String intxnId,@RequestParam String message, HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){

        String contentType= "text/html;charset=UTF-8";
        response.setContentType(contentType);
        //response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        try {
            request.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        response.setContentType("text/plain;charset=UTF-8"); 

        System.out.println("Send Message UTF-8 ----------------- "+ message);

    String json = null;
    BasicChatProtocol protocol = CustomerManagement.protocol.put(intxnId, chatProtocol.getProtocol());
    HashMap<String,String> result = send.send(message, intxnId, protocol);
    result.put("name",(String) session.getAttribute("nickName"));
    ObjectMapper map = new ObjectMapper();
    if(result.size()!= 0){
        try {
            json = map.writeValueAsString(result);
            result.clear();
            result = null;
            System.out.println("Send Message  :::::::: : "+json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
return json;

}
```

My `jQuery-AJAX` will be:

```
function sendMessage(){
    var intxnId = $("#hide").val();
    var message = $("#message").val();
    alert("send  : \n intxnId : "+intxnId+"\nmessage : "+message);
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST", 
        cache: false,
        url: contexPath + "/sendMessage.html",
        async:     true,
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
        scriptCharset: "utf-8",
        dataType: 'html',
        data: "intxnId=" + intxnId +"&message="+ encodeURIComponent(message),

        success: function(response){

            if(response != null && response !="" && response !="null"){

                var txt = '{"data":['+response+']}';
                var json = eval ("(" + txt + ")");
                for(i =0;i<json.data.length;i++){
                    var data = json.data[i];

                    var name = data.name;
                    var message = data.message;
                    var time = data.time;

                    alert("Name : "+name+"\nMessage : "+message+"\ntime : "+time);
                    var createHTML  = send(name,message,time);
                    $("#messageDisplayArea").append(createcreateHTML);
                };
            }

        },  
        error: function(e){  
            alert('Error: ' + e);  
        }, 

    }); 
}
```

But when I send the local language message `அவர்களுக்கு`(Tamil language), I  got only `???????` in the `alert box` and the `view page`.

But I got the `local language` in the console(`SysOut in controller`) and all `Special Characters` works.

**Note :** I think I am having the problem with `response from the controller`.Because when I send the `message` to the `controller` I got the `message as small boxes` in `javascript alert`. But when the `response` came I am getting the `?????` in the `alert box`.

My console prints,

```
Send Message UTF-8 ----------------- அவர்களுக்கு
Mesge what I send :::: அவர்களுக்கு
Send Message :::::::: : {"message":"அவர்களுக்கு","time":"time","name":"Human"}
```

I don't know what I am missing.

**Note :** I am not using any `data base`.

Hope our stack users will give a better solution. Good answers are definitely appreciated.

Comment: where are you getting those ?????? characters? In the spring controller, in the console? I'm pretty sure your javascript is sending the wright chars

Comment: In the controller `sysout` I am getting the local language in the console .But in `alert box` and in the `view page` I am getting `?????`

Comment: I  think I am having the problem with response from the `controller`.Because when I send the `message` to the `controller` I got the `message as small boxes` in `javascript` alert. But when the response came I am getting the `?????` in the alert box.

Comment: ANSWER : This is one of the useful reference http://charlie.cu.cc/2012/08/spring-mvc-ajax-request-with-utf-8-support/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tried your javascript with this test controller:

```
@Controller
public class TestController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = POST, produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    public @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity<String> sendMessage(HttpSession session, @RequestParam String intxnId, @RequestParam String message, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        System.out.println("Send Message UTF-8 ----------------- " + message);

        String json = null;
        HashMap<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();
        result.put("name", "test");
        result.put("message", message);
        result.put("time", "time");
        ObjectMapper map = new ObjectMapper();
        if (!result.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                json = map.writeValueAsString(result);
                System.out.println("Send Message  :::::::: : " + json);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders(); 
        responseHeaders.add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8"); 
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(json, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

It works like a charm, and I see UTF-8 characters from the response in the alert popup, using chrome browser.

My test.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <input type="text" id="hide" />
        <input type="text" id="message"/>
        <button id="button">test</button>
        <div id="messageDisplayArea"></div>


        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $('#button').on('click', sendMessage);

        function sendMessage() {
            var intxnId = $("#hide").val();
            var message = $("#message").val();
            alert("send  : \n intxnId : " + intxnId + "\nmessage : " + message);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/test",
                async: true,
                data: "intxnId=" + intxnId + "&message=" + encodeURIComponent(message),
                success: function(response) {

                    if (response !== null && response !== "" && response !== "null") {
                        alert("Name : " + response.name + "\nMessage : " + response.message + "\ntime : " + response.time);
                        $("#messageDisplayArea").append(message);
                    }

                },
                error: function(e) {
                    alert('Error: ' + e);
                },
            });
        }
    </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Can you post the `JQuery-ajax` code that you have used or the full code?

Comment: Still getting the same `?????`in the `ajax success alert`.did you used the configuration for `utf-8` in `web.xml`  ?

Comment: Yes, I have the same org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter configured

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32956/discussion-between-kite-player-and-abel-pastur)

Answer (score 3):

Can you try using produces = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8" in the @RequestMapping

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = POST, produces = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8")
    public @ResponseBody
```

also check this:
[UTF-8 encoding problem in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649329/utf-8-encoding-problem-in-spring-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

I would try some debugging in the browser. Use some developer tools in your browser ([Developer Tools in Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/), [Firebug extension](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox or any other such tool in any other browser) and try to check HTTP response you are getting for your ajax - check if HTTP headers are correctly set (utf8 encoding, etc.) and maybe if ypur special characters are displayed correctly there - so you can see, if you are getting correct answer from the server.

BTW - I dont see any error in code you posted, everything looks good. Just double check, that page on that you are displaying response with ajax, has utf8 encoding set...