# Json response issue in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer, response

I am having a problem in displaying json response using ajax in internet explorer. The other browsers displaying it correctly. But in internet explorer it is displayed as ??????.

Response Header is

```
Key Value
Response    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
Pragma  no-cache
Cache-Control   private, max-age=0, no-store, no-cache
Expires Fri, 22 Jan 2016 03:50:17 GMT
Cache-Control   no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma  no-cache
Expires 0
X-XSS-Protection    1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options  nosniff
Content-Type    text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length  145
Date    Fri, 22 Jan 2016 03:50:17 GMT
```

But in Internet Explorer Response body is given as

```
 {"data":null,"status":2,"message":"Request succeeded","errors":{"data1":"??????????????","data2":"??????????????"}}
```

In all other browsers it is displayed correctly

Comment: The browser doesn't control the response body. Sounds like you have a server issue.

Comment: There must be something missing in the `request body` which is not expected by your server side logic and it responds that way.

Comment: It is working well in all other browsers. In response body also getting message in the desired format in those browsers. I am trying to display japanese message. But in response header I am setting charset as UTF-8

Comment: @OP, Is there any way one could reproduce this issue ? If yes, kindly provide the same..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found answer for that. Its a problem in server. We have to set response content type as text/plain in server. Following is my code that fixed my issue.

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/uploading", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8")
public @ResponseBody
String upload(@RequestParam(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file, Locale locale) {
//opertions here
return jsonSerializer.serialize(message);
}
```

For more details go through the link
[UTF-8 encoding problem in Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649329/utf-8-encoding-problem-in-spring-mvc)