# utf8 charset with Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, utf-8, thymeleaf

When using Spring with Thymeleaf all my Cyrillic characters are shown as `?????` on pages.

Using

`@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/html; charset=utf-8")`

as it was suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11866822/1479414 and here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12023816/1479414 doesn't help.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The answer can be found [here](http://forum.thymeleaf.org/UTF8-charset-problem-td3608879.html):

Property `characterEncoding` should be explicitly set for `templateResolver` and `ThymeleafViewResolver`:

```
<bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    ...
    <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    ...
</bean>

<bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    ...
    <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    ...
</bean>
```

Comment: I've changed both settings but the unicode characters still do not render properly. Is there any other setting that could be misconfigured?

Comment: I don't know. I have not been working with Tapestry for two years. It might be that something has changed since that time

Answer (score 5):

working for me. java config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.projectName.controller")
public class MVCConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer, ApplicationContextAware {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws 
         BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver(){
        ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        thymeleafViewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        thymeleafViewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
       return thymeleafViewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public TemplateEngine templateEngine(){
       SpringTemplateEngine springTemplateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
       springTemplateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
       springTemplateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
       return springTemplateEngine;
   }

   @Bean
   public ITemplateResolver templateResolver(){
       SpringResourceTemplateResolver springResourceTemplateResolver = new 
                        SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
       springResourceTemplateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
       springResourceTemplateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
       springResourceTemplateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
       springResourceTemplateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
       springResourceTemplateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
       return springResourceTemplateResolver;
  }

   @Override
   public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
      registry
            .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
   }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Comment: Boiletplate advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

in Config

```
public class SpringConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    public SpringConfig(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.setEnableSpringELCompiler(true);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }
}
```

In ServletInitializer

```
public class MySpringMvcDispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{SpringConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        CharacterEncodingFilter filter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        filter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        filter.setForceEncoding(true);
        return new Filter[] { filter };
    }
}
```

Comment: This is all good, until Filter[] getServletFilters(), that isn't in AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer, but in AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer. How did you override it? @psyopus

Comment: [Link to documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.html). 
AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer
extends AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer

Answer (score 0):

If you have added `<property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>` in the bean configuration for view resolver and still text are not shown in correct format then the problem is in the properties/resource_bundle files.

Try encoding UTF-8 or non-English characters with native2ascii tool. (its included in the java_home/bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I put below 2 lines in application.properties file

```
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=true
spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8
```

(Korean)Reference: https://blog.thjang.net/33

Answer (score 0):

With Spring WebFlux, I've restricted the view resolver to use `text/html; charset=UTF-8` as the only supported content type. I've used a custom `WebFluxConfigurer` for that (in Kotlin):

```kotlin
class CustomWebFluxConfigurer(
    private val viewResolver: ThymeleafReactiveViewResolver
) : WebFluxConfigurer {
    override fun configureViewResolvers(registry: ViewResolverRegistry) {
        viewResolver.supportedMediaTypes =
            listOf(MediaType.parseMediaType("text/html; charset=UTF-8"))
        registry.viewResolver(viewResolver)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I think in thymeleaf html page you are using th:text with html element, th:text it just display normal text,

if you want use special charter with your thymeleaf html page so just need to change for example

> th:utext="${yourcontroller_var}"

or

> th:utext="#{properties_var}"

For example

```
<div th:utext="${user.name}"> Test! </div> // for your controller variable
```

And

```
<div th:utext="#{message.username}"> UserName! </div> // for your properties variable
```

Nothing do other configuration for using special character with thymeleaf html page.

Hope you will fix your problem

Comment: You are wrong, this will not fix problem when page has static text and file is in `utf-8` encoding.

Comment: @Andremoniy what would fix this?