# Encoding problem in POST method Spring and Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, forms, encoding, thymeleaf

I have made a simple form where a user enters a name and then this name is stored in the database. I'm using `Spring MVC` and `Thymeleaf`. My database is `MySQL`. The problem occurred when I was trying to enter non-latin characters.
[image]

After storing the non-latin `name` in the database, I tried to display it on the webpage, but instead of cyrillic characters I got strange characters like this:

> Ð˜Ð¼Ñ

- I'm sure that encoding in the database is correct because when I tried to
  store a non-latin name using `MySQL Workbench` the encoding was
  right.
- Thymeleaf encoding is also set to UTF-8. Non-lating characters are displayed correctly when I put
  them, for example, in a tag like this:

> `<h1> Заголовок </h1>`

I have already tried:

- adding this line in the html file: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">`
- adding this attribute in the `form` tag: `<form accept-charset="UTF-8"  ...`

But nothing works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you try to specify the charset in the url data source ? spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/YOUR_DB_NAME?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8

Comment: I tried but nothing changed

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36397227/13397146

Comment: I tried it earlier. GET request started work correctly with non-latin characters after adding this configurations. Unfortunately, it doesn't work for POST

Comment: Specify the `utf8mb4` character set on all tables and text columns in your database. More at [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/). You are facing to a simple [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case like in Python `'Имя'.encode('utf-8').decode('cp1252','ignore')` (returns `'Ð˜Ð¼Ñ'`).

Answer (score 1):

I have searched a lot and at last, I have found a solution.

**- The first one I would rather call a workaround than a solution:**

```
    @PostMapping
    public String create(@RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("age") int age) {      

        byte[] bytes = name.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
        name = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8); // now "name" contains characters in the correct encoding

        ...
    }
```

**- The second solution looks much better in my opinion:**
At first, create a `Filter` class and set the encoding of the POST request there:

```
   public class RequestFilter extends HttpFilter {
        @Override
        protected void doFilter(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException
        {
            request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
```

Then you should register a `Filter` in `web.xml`

```
 <filter>
    <filter-name>filter_nane</filter-name>
    <filter-class>class_path_to_filter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>filter_nane</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
  </filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem. Thank you for your answer @gurmigou. You showed me the way to go, and I found an even better solution.

```
    <filter>
    <filter-name>filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>encoding</param-name>
      <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```