# HTML escape with Spring MVC and Jackson Mapper

Tags: spring-mvc, jackson, html-escape-characters

I am going to escape HTML in Spring MVC with Jackson Mapper to avoid XSS attack. I search for escaping with Jackson alone and how to config Jackson in Spring. I tried to export json with text like `"<" ">"`, I expected it to escape them to `&#60;` and `&#62;`. For example, I added some text enclosed with "bold tag" `<b>`, I expected to see plain bold tag text in the front end html but it ended up so that the text is shown in bold style in the front end html page.

Below is my approach. I don't know why it didn't work out.

```
public class CustomObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {  
    public CustomObjectMapper() {
        this.getJsonFactory().setCharacterEscapes(new CustomCharacterEscapes());
    }
}

public class CustomCharacterEscapes extends CharacterEscapes {
    private final int[] asciiEscapes;
    
    public CustomCharacterEscapes() {
        int[] esc = CharacterEscapes.standardAsciiEscapesForJSON();
        esc['<'] = CharacterEscapes.ESCAPE_STANDARD;
        esc['>'] = CharacterEscapes.ESCAPE_STANDARD;
        esc['&'] = CharacterEscapes.ESCAPE_STANDARD;
        esc['\''] = CharacterEscapes.ESCAPE_STANDARD;
        asciiEscapes = esc;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int[] getEscapeCodesForAscii() {
        return asciiEscapes;
    }
    
    @Override
    public SerializableString getEscapeSequence(int ch) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here is the Spring Bean configuration:

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <array>
            <bean id="jsonConverter"
                class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="objectMapper">
                    <bean class="x.y.z.CustomObjectMapper" />
                </property>
            </bean>
        </array>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: First a couple of general comments...I would suggest re-visiting your punctuation.  I am well aware that a lot of people on this site do not speak native english, but your posting is one huge run-on sentence.  I had to read it 3 times just to get a sense of where each statement ended.  Also, split your code into two separate blocks.  The site is thinking the Java code is XML because you blobbed them all together.  This way we can see some syntax highlighting.

Comment: General comments aside, can you please explain what you are trying to do exactly?  If I can regurgitate what I read, it sounds to me like you are trying to return HTML but use the MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter to convert some special characters?  Why are you using the MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter for that?  And why would you want to convert those characters?  Or, are you saying you are returning HTML in a JSON response, and the resulting JSON by default is incorrect because it's not converting the characters or espaping them properly?

Comment: I have edited my post, I am quite a newbie to stackoverflow, thanks for your advise @CodeChimp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never tried to write my own `HttpMessageConverter`, but I did find [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019162/custom-httpmessageconverter-with-responsebody-to-do-json-things) that seems pretty relevant to what you want to do.  In looking at their solution vs. what you posted here, I can say the biggest differences I noticed was that you did not seem to implement/override the following:

1. `protected boolean supports(Class<?> clazz)`, which indicates which class type you are supporting (I would recon in your case this would be Object or Serializable if you want it to be generic enough to handle every possibility, or some class specific to your domain objects)
2. `protected Object readInternal(Class<? extends Object> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage)`, looks like it's used for the request-side
3. `protected void writeInternal(Object t, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage)`, which looks like it's used for the response-side

Another approach might be to simple create a custom Jackson serializer in conjunction with `@ResponseBody`.  Or, better yet, if you have a value that is user-driven, and your storing it in a database, escape the values prior to insertion.  That way you don't need to do anything at all, and the value(s) in question would be "safe" from end-to-end.  If you wanted to get crazy-fancy, you could write a custom `java.beans.PropertyEditor` that escapes Strings for HTML and plug that into the mix using the `InitBinder`.

Finally, I would like to recommend that, instead of trying to replace the characters on your own, you use something like [Apache Commons-Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/)'s [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html) to escape the values.

Comment: I did it by making a custom Jackson serializer.
Thanks @CodeChimp!

Comment: You should validate input and escape output.

Comment: I agree, it's always good practice to validate all inputs, including those from non-human sources.

Comment: BTW, I wanted to  mention that it seems all of the StringEscapeUtils methods linked are marked deprecated. Perhaps there are even better ways of doing this these days?

Comment: @jpierson The `@Deprecation` at the top explains the replacement:  "as of 3.6, use commons-text StringEscapeUtils instead".  It looks like the functionality was split out to that other library.