# Gson serialization error class com.activeandroid.DatabaseHelper declares multiple JSON fields named mContext

Tags: android, gson, resttemplate, android-annotations, activeandroid

The error im getting is "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class com.activeandroid.DatabaseHelper declares multiple JSON fields named mContext"

I am using AndroidAnnotations RestClient to pull data from my Web Service and serialize into POJOs. The serializations worked fine while using ORMLite but i recently decided to try out Active Android and now my classes extends Model. Gson is serializing the parent class which i have no control over. Any way I can only include certain fields or maybe just return plain JSON from the RestClient and do the serialization a different way

```
@Rest(rootUrl = "http://stuff...com", converters = { GsonHttpMessageConverter.class })
    public interface RestClient {
    @Get("/AndroidController/createFacebookUser?facebookToken={facebookToken}&catIds=    {catIds}")
    User createFacebookUser(String facebookToken,String catIds);
}
```

and the User model is

```
@Data
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User extends Model {
@Column(name = "SystemID")
private String systemID;
@Column(name = "Name")
private String name;
public List<GameEntry> items() {
    return getMany(GameEntry.class, "Category");
}

public User(){}
```

}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gson provides multiple ways of excluding fields and types from Serialization and Deserialization. Take a look at [Excluding Fields From Serialization and Deserialization](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Excluding-Fields-From-Serialization-and-Deserialization), specifically the usage of `@Expose` annotation and user-defined [`ExclusionStrategy`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/ExclusionStrategy.html).

Answer (score 4):

I Created my own Serializer which extended AbstractHttpMessageConverter following the answer here

[Custom HttpMessageConverter with @ResponseBody to do Json things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019162/custom-httpmessageconverter-with-responsebody-to-do-json-things)

Only thing i changed was that i made the Gson and used the @Expose on the fields i wanted serialized

```
private Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
```