# Spring MVC - adding a filter to a controller with the request body available for manipulation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, filter

I have a controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/player")
public class PlayerController extends AbstractController {      

@RequestMapping(value = "/doSomething", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public int doSomeThing(@RequestBody SomeDTO someDTO , HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {

this.playerService.doSomething(
                 someDTO );

return SERVER_OK;
}

 // Tons of similar methods here
}
```

I would like to create a filter that will intercept all the calls to this controller and will have access to the `@RequestBody` Object object      that each of these methods receives. I would like to manipulate this `@RequestBody` object.

Is that possible?

Comment: No not with a filter. Also why would you want to manipulate the arguments before they reach the controller.

Comment: I would like to validate username \ password from the dto. is there a better way through spring security?

Comment: And why should that be done in the filter and not in the controller? That belongs, imho, to the controller not a filter.

Comment: I would like to prevent the scenario where a programmer forgets to add the authenticate line in the controller method, if the filter will do that, he cannot make this mistake.

Comment: It is a create method, so I don't see why the username/password for the current user would be inside the `PlayerAccountDTO`? For some reason that sounds wrong and doesn't even belong there.

Comment: This is a code example, its not the real deal, the real code should be an api we are exposing for users with valid username\password. please ignore the methods\dtos names.  I Edited my post

Comment: And you're idea is to include the username/password in each and every resource you expose, seems still scary to me? (Or you're explanation is a bit of). If you use rest you can also use Basic or Digest authentication both of which are perfectly supported by Spring Security.

Comment: This api can be used by many customers, i would like to avoid opening a session for the users. it should be a stateless service

Comment: Check the bean validation integration. @Valid on the parameter.

Comment: You could create a custom message converter. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019162/custom-httpmessageconverter-with-responsebody-to-do-json-things

Comment: Why would you need a session, spring security can work perfectly without a session.

Comment: Deinum, Where exactly spring security authentication in a session less takes the credentials from? the DTO? it is a service for other applications , not browsers, so typing username\password in the standard http authentication way is not an option.

Comment: Urbanleg, stateless service means that your client has to provide credentials on every api call and your backend has to validate these credentials on every api call. [HTTP Basic authentication](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2617#page-5) is just a normal HTTP header

Comment: Take a look Dave Syer's  answer to, "How to add a filter class in Spring Boot?" at  http://stackoverflow.com/a/19830906/266531